# Python Google Drive Authentification - Error: admin_policy_enforced

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am using python to upload or download files on Google Drive. This is the most important part of my code:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from apiclient import errors
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient import errors
import os 
import csv

#####################################
try :
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()

if not creds or creds.invalid:
    print("Create new data storage file ...")
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = client.OOB_CALLBACK_URN
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
    print ("Storage")

DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

The python-script worked fine for 2 month. But since yesterday I get this error if I start my script:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: admin_policy_enforced

Company security policies do not allow this app to connect to your Company account data. Please contact your local helpdesk for any support.

Request Details
client_id=XXXYYYZZZ.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
access_type=offline
response_type=code
```

My admin rights have not been changing till now. Do someone have an idea?

Comment: is this a gsuite account you are accessing?

Comment: It is a normal google drive account via company. I tested it with my private account and it works. So it's not a problem of my computer or script. It's only a problem of my google account, which is conntect with my company account

Comment: What do you mean its your company drive account?  Is it a gsuite or google for work account.   Assuming that you are using web credentails have you been though the review process?  https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html

Comment: I don't know. For me it's the same because gsuite also provides tools for work. What I know is that it works great till yesterday at 10 am. I executed the script and 1 minute later it failed. And I am not using web, I set it on "other"

Comment: I would contact your gsuite admin see what they did at 10 am yesterday.  Google isnt going to randomly remove your access.

Comment: They cannot help me. Is there any alternative to upload/download files via on Google Drive with python if I get an  security "policies do not allow" error?

Comment: No if the Gsuite admin has shut down the permissions for this there is nothing you can do.